# Why cant I animate using shape keys or locroc

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, shape-keys

Thank you for looking in to my problem.
I am having an issue applying shape keys or loc roc to my scene.  I am trying to animate one of the tentacles i have or just have shape keys move the mesh so that it can look like it's floating but when ever I apply loc roc or create a shape key nothing happens. I've been using a curve modifier to move the mesh around.  Is this why I cannot animate?

I've attached a link to the blend file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TUsHGsixeDUOL0bCVrLPKSemdz7Pqu3a/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use shape keys, they seemed to be empty though (I'd use shape keys to make the tentacles ribbon/wave-like motion for the edges).

For the tentacle motion I'd use bendy bones -

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to show me what is possible! I really appreciate you taking the time to respond. I've been scratching my head for hours on how to add a single bone to this curved object. Please tell me, what are the circles around the tentacles or can you send me the file? which ever is easiest. again, thank you for your help.

Comment: absolutely - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ft90AxJNEy0R-TAOvOdEuDjHk0CUkeG3/view?usp=sharing

it's pretty easy, just add a few bones along those curves, set them to bendy, increase the segments by a few, and change the bone's viewport display to custom mesh (in this case the circles) to make it look neater and easier to work with.